# Only show 4hr fractals no matter the timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to show 4hr fractals on the 15 min timeframe. The following code will only show the fractals when I am actually on the 4hr but not on the 15 min as I hoped. I am using the `request.security()` but probably incorrectly. Not sure the right solution

```
//@version=5
indicator("4h fractals on 15m", overlay = true)

ticker = syminfo.tickerid

fourHourHigh = request.security(ticker, "240", high)
fourHourLow = request.security(ticker, "240", low)

filteredtopf = fourHourHigh[4] < fourHourHigh[2] and fourHourHigh[3] <= fourHourHigh[2] and fourHourHigh[2] >= fourHourHigh[1] and fourHourHigh[2] > fourHourHigh[0]
filteredbotf = fourHourLow[4] > fourHourLow[2] and fourHourLow[3] >= fourHourLow[2] and fourHourLow[2] <= fourHourLow[1] and fourHourLow[2] < fourHourLow[0]

plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Filtered Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), offset=-2)
plotshape(filteredbotf, title='Filtered Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), offset=-2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `fourHourHigh` will change when it is a new bar on the higher timeframe. Otherwise it will keep its value. So, if you are on the 15-min timeframe and requesting data from the 4h timeframe, its value will change every 15 bars.

`fourHourHigh[4]` will **NOT** refer to `fourHourHigh[4]` on the higher timeframe. It will refer to `fourHourHigh[4]` on your chart's timeframe. And that value will change every 15 bars as I said.

What you need to do is, together with the `high`, you should also request the value of `high[1]`, `high[2]` etc. from the higher timeframe and use them in your calculations.

```
[fourHourHigh, fourHourHigh_1, fourHourHigh_2, fourHourHigh_3, fourHourHigh_4] = request.security(ticker, "240", [high, high[1], high[2], high[3], high[4]])

filteredtopf = fourHourHigh_4 < fourHourHigh_2 and fourHourHigh_3 <= fourHourHigh_2 and fourHourHigh_2 >= fourHourHigh_1 and fourHourHigh_2 > fourHourHigh
```

Comment: Thank you that make sense. I have one last issue I get 16 arrows plotted each time. I only need the first 15min bar of the 4hr fractal I have the arrow. Also I do a offset=-2 Normally for plotting a fractal but since I am on the 15min and the data is from 4hr would this need to change? Thanks

Comment: I have measured from where the fractal occurs on the 4hr the actual 16 arrows are drawn 11:15 hours or 45 bars latter

Comment: You can add `gaps=barmerge.gaps_on` to your `security()` call. That should fix the first issue.

Comment: For the second issue, you cannot know where exactly the fractal is on your chart's timeframe. You cannot get this information from the `security()`. For a fractal, it could be 5 bars from the current bar, for another fractal, it could be 10 bars from the current bar. So, the distance is not fixed. Therefore, you cannot use the `plotshape()` function.

Comment: The way I would do this is, I wouldn't use `security()` at all. Instead, I would manually keep track of the high/low of the higher timeframe, and also the bar indices of those bars (on your chart's timeframe). You can use the `timeframe.change()` function to see if it is a new bar on the higher timeframe.

Comment: Once you know the high price and bar index of that bar, you would then use `label.new()´ to mark that bar.

Comment: First issue solved thanks. I see that each arrow gets printed 47 bars latter which is really 48. This means it gets printed 3 4hr bars latter.  Since the code for the 4hr had an offset of -2 then I should be moving the 15 min bars back 32 plus the 15 bars. this does actually mark the correct location. Really profitable strategy so worth the work :-) Have I missed something do you think?